# multiple resolution in android Unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, resolution

I have been creating a android game, but I need create it for more devices. Now, I try the game on my smartphone Samsung Galaxy S (with resolution 480 x 800), but when I try start it on my tablet Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1, it stretches pictures, but it is not full screen, I have same free space. Plese, how can I stretch it to full screen? I would like creat the game for more devices, not only for one :D

For any help thanks, Andrew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is make a different version for each screen, you can set the game view to different screen sizes and then depending on the size of the screen, create bigger or smaller GUI elements. In the gameview you can see how different GUI elements are placed while you change them.